# First item (ImageView) in a Gridview has null value for field mAttachInfo

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am writing an Android application, using a `GridView` to load a list of `ImageView` items through an `Adapter`. It all works fine, except the first item loaded in `GridView` had `null` value for its `mAttachInfo` variable.

I guess it could be because the first item is either selected or focused, which causes the `mAttachInfo` set to `null`, other items have correct `mAttachInfo` set.

Comment: show me the code, please.

Comment: i meet the same problem.and i don't know why.